# Grammar (complex sentence)

Tags: grammar

Is this correct grammar? I changed the actual content so that my teacher doesn't get angry.

> In the United States, turtles can be yellow, as the chemicals in the water dye their shells.

That isn't true. I made it up.

Comment: Even if you didn't made it up, it would still be acceptable grammatically. Why you think it might not be would be a much better question.

Comment: I'm in general pretty terrible about using commas, so I'm always critical of my usage.

Comment: Ah. Commas can be irritating, and do tend to be overused by many. In this case, however, it's necessary; without it, it would cause the reader to assume "...yellow as the chemicals [that]... until they stumbled onto the rest. The comma prevents that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **"In the United States, turtles can be yellow, as the chemicals in the water dye their shells,"** is an example of correct usage and punctuation.